# iOS WKWebView video autoplay

Tags: video, wkwebview, autoplay

I have a link to PowerPoint presentation on Microsoft SharePoint disk.
https://bambooagile629-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/personal/dg_bambooagile629_onmicrosoft_com/EeVRsWBAEDdFliPhjYhhLMABSsiV04X5Oqa6rO8uGQldJA?action=embedview&wdEaa=1
The presentation has only one slide with embedded video. I need the video to autoplay. The video has no audio track. I added the next configuration to WKWebView.

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

But the video doesn't autoplay. All desktop browsers and android webview autoplay
this video. Is it possible to autoplay this video in WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send Javascript to your Wkwebview after it loaded like `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].play()`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. document.getElementsByTagName("video") returns an empty array. This video is in Microsoft iframe. And we don't have access to its contents.